# How to call native method with 'null' parameter

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need call native method like that:

java code:

```
private native Object SendFiles(String strEmail, DeviceInfo info, String [] arrFiles, int cntFiles, ID idRequest);
```

call SendFiles();

```
SendFiles(strEmail, null, arrFiles, cntFiles, requestID);
```

and c++ code:

```
jobject Java_com_xxxxx_xxxxx_controller_CoreController_SendFiles(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject obj, jstring strEmail, jobject jinfo, jobjectArray jarrFiles, jint cntFiles, jobject jidRequest){
         .........

          if(jinfo == NULL)       // here crashes !!!!!!!
             doSomething();

         ............
}
```

Java 'null' can be sent to c 'NULL'?

how i can do  this?

Comment: Is it really there where it crashes or are you accessing jinfo elsewhere? To me it seems that doSomething is only processed if jinfo is not available, but I don't see any mechanism to avoid execution of other code?

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on c++ `NULL` checks on multiple posts, such as [Checking for a null object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099882/checking-for-a-null-object-in-c) or [Checking if this is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844005/checking-if-this-is-null) or [How do we check if a pointer is NULL pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185821/so-how-do-we-check-if-a-pointer-is-null-pointer)

however this post seems to give the most straight-forward approach:
[Return a "NULL" object if search result not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639255/c-return-a-null-object-if-search-result-not-found)

Comment: It still doesn't explain the behavior as at least in JDK 1.7 `jobject` is defined as `typedef _jobject *jobject;` so it's not a call by reference, it's a call by pointer. And the pointer should be checkable for NULL or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`jobject` is a pointer datatype on the C++ side. When you pass a `null` object from Java, C++ receives it as a `NULL` pointer. It's OK to compare.

The crash probably has to do with something else. Insert some diagnostic output and debug.